# Count the element of array inside a list

Tags: python, arrays

I  have arrays inside list and I want to count the number of element in an array from two different lists instead of counting the list items.

**code**

```
import numpy as np
def count_total(a,b):
#count the total number of element for two arrays in different list
x,y=len(a),len(b)
result=[]
for a1 in a:
    for b2 in b:
        result.append(x+y)
return result

a=[np.array([2,2,1,2]),np.array([1,3])]
b=[np.array([4,2,1])]
c=[np.array([1,2]),np.array([4,3])]

print(count_total(a,b))
print(count_total(a,c))
print(count_total(b,c))
```

**Actual output**

```
[3, 3]
[4, 4, 4, 4]
[3, 3]
```

**Desired output**

```
[7,5]
[6,6,4,4]
[5,5]
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: It's not clear how your desired output corresponds to your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me from you examples you want all the possible ways to sum the length of the arrays. This can be achieved with `itertools.product`. Here is my code:

```
from itertools import product

def count_total(a,b):
    return [sum(map(len, i)) for i in product(a, b)]
```

The product return all possible arrangements for one element each from a and b. Then for each arrangement, we take the len of the parts in the arrangement from each list, then add them together with `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

Bug is in line 4, x and y are assigned list lengths rather than array lengths.

Replace the line 4-8

```
x,y=len(a),len(b)
result=[]
for a1 in a:
    for b2 in b:
        result.append(x+y)
```

with

```
y= lambda x:len(x)
result=[]
for a1 in a:
    for b1 in b:
        result.append(y(a1) + y(b1))
```